# firing function at login within class

Tags: wp-admin, login

I've got a function that I'm trying to fire at wp_signon (grabs data from a remote server and updates accordingly). I'm running the function within a class that is on a secondary file in a plugin (i.e. brought in with a require_once). For the life of me, I cannot get this function to run at all.

```
add_action( 'wp_signon', array(&$this, 'login_pull_updates'), 40, 3 );

        function login_pull_updates() {
            update_option('ap_login_run', 'YES I DID');
        }
```

I'm using that now to just test and confirm it's running at all, and it won't fire. Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, I've tried the same function with wp_login instead of wp_signon and it still didn't work

Comment: On what action is the class object created?

Comment: add_action init

Comment: Are you sure an action `'wp_signon'` exists? Could not find it …

Comment: I realized I should be using wp_login (got confused) but the problem remains. it appears to be related to the fact that it's in a class, since a stand-alone function works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wp_signon doesn't exist (at least according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) but I tried tossing this into a fresh theme and it seems to work:

```
class TestThing {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_login', array($this, 'login_pull_updates') );
    }

    function login_pull_updates($login, &$user) {
        update_option('ap_login_run', 'YES I DID');
    }

}

$test = new TestThing();
```